# querySelector возвращает null

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться: есть html файл **test.html**, и есть js файл **scripts.js**. Скрипт точно подключен, но когда пытаюсь найти элемент через
`const a = document.querySelector('p'); console.log(p);`. В консоль выводиться `null`.

А когда пытаюсь тоже самое проделать в html файле(`const a = document.querySelector(p); console.log(p);`), то все работает. Подскажите с чем это может быть связанно.

Код **test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>test</p>
    <script>
        const a = document.querySelector('p');
        console.log(a);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Вывод в консоль: `<p>test</p>`**

Код **scripts.js**

```
const a = document.querySelector('p');
console.log(a);
```

**Вывод в консоль: `null`**

Попробовал все варианты(класс, id) все равно выводит `null`.

*Заранее спасибо за помощь.*

Comment: Если вы подключили скрипт внутри `<head>`, значит в этот момент никакой `<body>` ещё не успел появиться, а значит и никакого `<p>` тоже не существует

Comment: Я попробывал и сделать так как вы сказали, но все равно не работает. К тому же в других файлах, где скрипт подключен в ```<head>``` все отлично работает.

Comment: Я вроде бы ничего не говорил делать. Что вы сделали-то?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что подключал скрипт в конце ```<body>```. Но результат был таким же.

Comment: Когда я подключаю в конце `<body>` то у меня всё работает (за исключением ошибки `redeclaration of const a` из-за дублирования скрипта, но если убрать один из скриптов, то всё работает)

Comment: Странно. Ладно завтра попробую еще повозиться. Спасибо за помошь.

Comment: Ну так вы определитесь, вы код пишите в отдельном файле или в том же документе. Зачем вы его и там и там и там дублируете? Смысла в этом нет

Comment: Чтобы проверять работает ли код вообще. Я изначально думал, что где-то совершаю опечатку(хотя ide не подсвечивал). Сейчас уже все нормально работает, не знаю что это было и с чем это было связанно, но утром когда включил пк все работала без каких-либо проблем.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Вообщем я так и не понял в чем была проблема, но после перезагрузки ПК все заработал. Все кто попытался помочь, огромное спасибо!**